# PHP - unsafe file edit, erasing all data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework, ini

I have existing `ini` file which is only for edit from Javascript actions.

But PHP/Javascript erase all the data in the ini file and leave one section with one line. (Sometimes its not erasing but when section4 or section5 its editing it erase the whole file and keep last one)

config.ini:

```
[slide1]
button0=6,298,273,425
[slide2]
button1=1005,313,1269,425
button0=6,298,273,425
[slide3]
button1=1005,313,1269,425
button0=6,298,273,425
[slide4]
button1=1005,313,1269,425
button0=6,298,273,425
[slide5]
button1=1005,313,1269,425
button0=6,298,273,425
button2=1005,313,1269,425
button3=6,298,273,425
[slide6]

[slide7]
```

PHP:

```
// EDIT only? (no erase, no delete, no new line add
function config_set($config_file, $section, $key, $value) {
    $config_data = parse_ini_file($config_file, true);
    $config_data[$section][$key] = $value;
    $new_content = '';
    foreach ($config_data as $section => $section_content) {
        $section_content = array_map(function($value, $key) {
            return "$key=$value";
        }, array_values($section_content), array_keys($section_content));
        $section_content = implode("\n", $section_content);
        $new_content .= "[$section]\n$section_content\n";
    }
    file_put_contents($config_file, $new_content);
}



config_set('config.ini', 'slide5', "button0", "1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,7");
echo 'updated';
```

jQuery:

```
$.get('draw_save.php', {
        test: 'none'
      }, function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
      });
```

EDIT: try safe write

```
function safefilerewrite($fileName, $dataToSave) {    
  if ($fp = fopen($fileName, 'w')) {
    $startTime = microtime(TRUE);
    do {            
      $canWrite = flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
      // If lock not obtained sleep 
      // for 0 - 100 milliseconds, to avoid collision and CPU load
      if(!$canWrite) usleep(round(rand(0, 100)*1000));
    } while ((!$canWrite)and((microtime(TRUE)-$startTime) < 5));

      //file was locked so now we can store information
      if ($canWrite) {            
        fwrite($fp, $dataToSave);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
      }
      fclose($fp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it not imply that `$new_content` remains empty? Thus replacing your file with nothing...

Comment: Impossible. Because its not empty it write at-least some.

Comment: I tried safe write. But still same. It erase the file data and keep 1 section.

Comment: Fair enough, it was the "erasing all data" that lead me to that...but it looks like you've solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delaying the write attempt fixed it.

```
 function save_later() {
    // Ajax 
    $.get('draw_save.php', {

    }, function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });    
  }



  var delay_saving = null;
  function delay_save() {
    delay_saving = setTimeout(function() {
      save_later();
    }, 200);
  }
```